# render or convert the html table within pdf using the XSL-FO

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, jira, velocity, xsl-fo

I am trying to export the data from a field of type Table Grid into a PDF format. While achieving it, I get a below html code of this table grid field exported into the PDF O/P. I am trying to convert this HTML table to XSL-FO and output it as a PDF. I am sorry I complete noob to this approach. How to transform this HTML table to PDF as final O/P.Can anybody share the exact approach of converting this HTML table to XSL-FO table and output it as PDF.

Below is the XSL-FO and Velocity template code to get the HTML reference of the customfield object and then using the **$pdfRenderer** tool I try to display the table grid value in the PDF export.

```
<!-- Table Grid Customfield 'customfield_10300' -->
    #set ($customfieldId = "customfield_10300")
    #set ($customfield = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject($customfieldId))
    #set ($moduleDescriptor = $customfield.getCustomFieldType().getDescriptor())
    #set ($fieldLayoutItem = ${fieldLayout.getFieldLayoutItem($customfieldId)})
    #set ($htmlMarkup = $moduleDescriptor.getViewHtml($customfield, "htmlMarkup",  $issue, $fieldLayoutItem)) 

    <fo:table space-before="3mm" border="thin solid #CCCCCC">
      <fo:table-body>
          <fo:table-row>
           <fo:table-cell padding="4px">
               <fo:block background-color="#EEEEEE" padding="4px" font-weight="bold" start-indent="4px" end-indent="4px">$i18n.getText($customfield.name):
               </fo:block>
             </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="4px">                                <fo:block>$pdfRenderer.asRendered($issue, $customfieldId, $htmlMarkup)       </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
 </fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
```

However, this **$htmlMarkup** displays the below complete HTML code for the table grid customfield than the value.

```
<div id="customfield_10300_grid-container" class="idalkogrid-view" style="overflow-y: visible; overflow-x:visible;" rel="customfield_10300" name="idalko-grid-field">
<table id="customfield_10300_grid"></table>
    <div id="customfield_10300_grid_pager"></div>
        <div id="customfield_10300_filter"></div>
            <table class="grid" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
            <tr bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
                <th>Summary</th>
                <th>Assignee</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Date due</th>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <td style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 2px;"> Table Grid Summary1 </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 2px;"> admin </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 2px;"> Open </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 2px;"> 2014-01-14 </td>
            </tr>
</table> 
</div>
```

How to make this **$htmlMarkup** variable display the table grid with proper values in the PDF

Comment: There are several ways to improve your post. **1** Replace the screenshot of your HTML code with actual HTML and indent it by four spaces. Nobody wants to type this up. **2** Say more clearly what you are intending to do: is it converting an HTML table to XSL-FO and output it as PDF?

Comment: Before you can write any XSLT, you need to know what you want to transform it to, and that means knowing what the XSL-FO you require looks like. If you know this, you should show the XSL-FO in your question. However, if you don't know XSL-FO then you really have two issues to sort out! In that case, it would be better to edit your question to purely focus on what the XSL-FO should look like. Once you have an answer for this, you can then ask another question about how XSLT can be used to transform to it.

Comment: To expand on Tim C comment, once you write the XSL FO for yourself, you will likely realize the correct process. Not going grid to HTML to FO, rather going direct to FO from the grid.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question and added the XSL-FO code which displays tries to render the **$htmlMarkup** velocity template variable using the $pdfRenderer tool. Can you please share your thoughts.

Comment: I totally agree with "Tim". But, if you don't know anything about XSLT-FO, you may use "Prince" tool http://www.princexml.com/ which is able to convert HTML to PDF format

Answer (score 0):

The JIRA add-on called [JIRA PDF View Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.pdfview) you were asking about, officially supports the [Table Grid Editor](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.idalko.jira.plugins.igrid) custom fields since version 3.4.0.

That means it does **not** require any custom coding, table fields will export to PDF by default.

See the [details](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-pdf-view-plugin/documentation/integrations#table-grid-editor) in the product documentation.

*(Disclaimer: this question is related to a commercial product and I'm a developer working on it.)*